# Proxy WebClients response through Flux Rest API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I'm new to Spring Web Flux. I'm trying to retrieve binary content from a web server using WebClient and stream the response through my API.

I have working code without Flux, but due to the nature of RestTemplate, the whole binary response is held in a buffer which requires too much memory.

EDIT:
I'm still using Spring MVC, so I'm trying to use WebClient and standard Spring Controller